# Strange behavior of SSRS Report Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-ax-2012, multivalue, reportparameter

Has anyone else experienced this issue ? I am designing a report in SSRS 2008 using Development tools for Dynamics AX 2012, I have several datasets and parameters in my report, the problem is that when I made any change in my main dataset, and refresh the dataset, some of my report parameters **FORGET** the **Multi Value** option, then I have to set the multi value to true again for all those parameters.

Is there any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have noticed this issue in past. To escape this issue, you can make the required changes in the report code (right click on report -> view code).